# Spinnaker build does not trigger on a re-push of an existing tag (like latest)

Tags: docker, triggers, spinnaker, amazon-ecr

The Spinnaker document says that a push to the Docker Registry will trigger Spinnaker Build.

We have configured the Automated Triggers to Docker Registry **(AWS ECR)**

However, the tag we are using is `:latest`

In the document it says **`Leave the Tag field blank. This will trigger on all new tags, but will not trigger on a re-push of an existing tag (like latest)`**

I want to know what is the reason for not redeploying a re-push or push of same tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind why re-push of an existing image tag does not work with Automated Triggers to Docker Registry is deployment reproducibility.

As a maintainer of Spinnaker repository mentions in their comment on issue: [Spinnaker not triggering pipeline when new image is released to Docker registry](https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2037):

> This is the intended behavior for the docker registry triggers, since deploying from the same tag is not reproduceable. See more [here](https://www.spinnaker.io/guides/tutorials/codelabs/kubernetes-source-to-prod/#kubernetes-source-to-prod).
> https://github.com/spinnaker/spinnaker/issues/2037#issuecomment-392570341

Taking a look at the problem from a [DevOps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DevOps) perspective.
Spinnaker - and [DevOps in general](https://medium.com/devopscurry/understanding-the-mutable-immutable-infrastructure-in-devops-world-64d33134e233) - prefers what is called "immutable infrastructure". Ref: search for "immutable" on [Spinnaker homepage](https://spinnaker.io/). Immutable infrastructure does not yet have a definition on Wikipedia that I could find. In place of a Wikipedia definition, below is some reference material on immutable infrastructure, found on Google:

- [DigitalOcean: What is immutable infrastructure](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/what-is-immutable-infrastructure)
- [HashiCorp: What is mutable vs immutable infrastructure](https://www.hashicorp.com/resources/what-is-mutable-vs-immutable-infrastructure)

For the scope of this question focusing only on the deployment reproducibility aspect of immutable infrastructure should be enough.
A mutable image, or a mutable tag (`latest` is a mutable tag) makes deployment reproducibility challenging. (Just run `docker run golang:latest go version` now, and a few weeks later to see what I mean.) So a mutable tag conflicts with making deployments reproducible, thus infrastructure immutability, and DevOps in general.